# What are my options with single-sign on with my scenario?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-3.5, asp.net-membership, single-sign-on

I have an ASP.NET MVC 2 application.  The username/passwords are stored in Microsoft ASP.NET Membership tables.  I have a client who has their own web application and they are going to have a link on the application that if the user is already logged into their web app and they click the link, it will take them to my web app, without asking them to login in.  I have seen many sso providers, but do I need to use google, openID, etc in order to use those?  Currently the user has direct access to my web app and they login using the ASP.NET Membership tables.  This is going to be cross domain, so it is my understanding that I can't use cookies. What are my options?

Comment: You could detect from what domain user is come, and this link can proceed user params which you can handle and authorize them

Comment: @TimurShahbanov - That is a good approach.  How secure would it be and has it been used before?

Comment: nope its just an idea, and about secure - i dont think is there any problems , you could anytime unapprove any user if needs.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own custom `Security Token Service(STS)` which will issue the token and then your `Relying Party Applications(RTP)` can use the same token to validate themselves to your Apps.

For
Building a simple custom STS using VS2012 & ASP.NET MVC

Have a Look here

http://chris.59north.com/post/2013/04/09/Building-a-simple-custom-STS-using-VS2012-ASPNET-MVC.aspx

http://chris.59north.com/post/2013/03/27/Claims-based-identities-in-ASPNET-MVC-45-using-the-standard-ASPNET-providers.aspx

Comment: Forgot to mention I am using Visual Studio 2008. Am I assuming correctly that this will work for Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Yes it will work but not tried yet. Its working for me in vs2010.